# Counting file lines in shell and in a script gives different results

Tags: bash, scripting, lines

For a bunch of files in a directory I want to get the number of lines for each one, store it 
in a variable and do additional stuff. Via shell I can do it without problems if I do

```
read NLINES <<<  $( cat file  |  wc  -l )
```

but if I do it in a script

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls *.dat `
do
    read NLINES <<<  $( cat $i  |  wc  -l )
done
```

I get

```
Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Why the difference? How could I fix it?

Comment: [Don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet your default shell isn't bash but something else. Leave the `#!/bin/bash` and replace it with `#!/bin/sh`, to let your script use the default shell.

I made this error the other way, when I tried to use some debian scripts on Ubuntu, where `#!/bin/sh` behaved differently from my assumed `#!/bin/bash`.